# Combining Symmetric and Asymmetric encryption

Tags: encryption, openssl, public-key-encryption, encryption-symmetric

I am trying to move a file from station A to station C securely, on the way from A to C there is another ** insecure ** station, B.

(A) -> (B) -> (C)

Station B receives the file from station A and pass it to station C.

I want to make sure that Station B will not be able to read the content of the file.

In order to enforce that I am using Symmetric and Asymmetric encryption to encrypt the file.

1. Generating a random symmetric key = SK on station A
2. Encrypt the file symmetrically using SK as the key.
3. Encrypting SK asymmetrically with C's public key = AK

Now I need to deliver C both AK and the Encrypted File.

Since B doesn't have the Private Key, he will not be able to retrieve SK and will not be able to decrypt the file.

Question:
1. Is there a way to combine AK and the encrypted File into one big file? (is there any standard way of doing this using OpenSSL). 
The only way i can think of is to make my own format: [AK Len][AK][Encrypted File]

Any libraries in python that can help doing that task?

Comment: If you're using ssl, it's not necessary to do any of what you're doing (unless you want the encrypted file to be stored encrypted with that same key). Ssl already establishes a symmetric/asymmetric protocol similar to what you describe, but using a dynamic asymmetric key pair (see diffie hellman).

Comment: The communication is SSL encrypted, but its not mandatory, i want the file to be Encrypted as well so station B will not be able to open it up.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there are several existing standards for encrypting files in this way.

I suggest using the [`gpg`](http://www.gnupg.org/) utility, which implements the OpenPGP standard.